# Gaussian curve for a given stock price and IV with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, statistics, data-visualization, gaussian, quantitative-finance

I would like to create an options trading tool that first requires a  gaussian curve ( implemented with `d3.js` ), that displays a probability of the stock being above or below a given price ( [In-the-Money] ) **`ITM price`**.

If a stock has a price of 100 dollars, and has a 1 year implied volatility ( **`IV`** ) of 20%, then the stock is said to have a 68% chance of being between $80 and $120 at the end of the year (100 +/- 20)... Basically, `IV` ( implied volatility ) tells the 1 standard deviation ( **`StDEV`** ) move to either side of the stock price.

If I understand correctly, `variance = ( StDEV )^2`

So, if a stock has an actual price of $100 and a 1 `StDEV` ( standard deviation ) expected move of 20 dollars in either direction, the `variance` would be .04 ( .2 ^2 ).

**`Q1:` Is this correct?**

**`Q2:`** And would the `mean` of the model be 100 dollars ( gaussian curves like the one below generally require a `variance` and `mean` )?

Generally, Gaussian bell curves display the `mean` as the peak of the curve, and I know that the stock price should be in the middle of the curve, as gaussian random walk states that a stock has a 50% chance of ending up above or below the current price after a given time period.

So, if a stock costs $100 dollars and has an `IV` of 20, the stock has a 50%  chance of ending up above $100 in a year, and a 50% percent chance of ending up below $100 in a year and there is an 82% chance ( 1 of the standard deviation ) that it will end up below $120 with only an 18% chance of ending up above $120.

**My question is:**

**`Q3:`** How would I modulate a `d3`-graph [like the one in the **example below**](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/88cb8a51cdce45f13c7e) to plug in a stock price and Implied Volatility (1 SD Move) to graph the likelihood of a stock ending up above or below a certain price?

I have tried substituting the stock price for the `mean` in the gaussian function, and `IV` for `sigma` and it is not working.

**`Q4:`** How do I change the gaussian function to fit the stock price and `IV`?

I know these subjects can get complex, but try to keep as simple as possible, please.

http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/88cb8a51cdce45f13c7e

Comment: Your std is more likely the 20 in your problem, which gives a variance of 400. The mean could be 100, but it depends what the model is. The mean is not the peak of the curve. The curve is roughly said a representation of the density of data points on the x axis, one of which (in the middle in the case of a Gaussian) is the mean.
Honestly, I'd say start with reading a book about basic statistics before applying them and ruining the world's economy.

Comment: @muraveill you were totally correct...sorry this is just learning experiment to understand how brokers make these models...in this case 20 is the standard deviation...What this curve shows is the density of the probability that a stock will expire above or below a certain price in a certain amount of days...The Peak is always at the .50 delta bc it represents the price in which the stock has a 50/50 chance of staying above or below, and the standard deviation mark resides where the options have a 68 percent chance of expiring in the money (or out of the money)...

Answer (score 0):

[image: https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/jc/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAbcAAAAJDE0ZWE1NDAwLTE0YTctNGM4Ni05ZmZiLTNhYWQyMmU4MTNiNQ.png]

**`A1:`** **Yes**, Drew, the calculus is correct

**`A2:`** **Yes and no**, the `ITM` is a conceptual value of an externally developed by a non-stationary multi-agent processes ( The Market rulez ), while a `mean` of a distribution is a stationary value related to a rather statically defined composition of such distribution ( be it named Gaussian or whatever else ).

**`A3:`** Depends a lot on what specific functionality you would like to compose & integrate into `3d.js` for the **`"Controller-part"` of the intelligent domain-specific visualiser** ( while `MVC`-jargon is re-used in many contexts, it originated from Xerox's PARCplace systems' Smalltalk as late as late 80-s last century, and until nowadays well depicts internal layers of specialisation of the GUI-presentation frameworks, so forgive both my reminiscence & my big respect for those brave guys around the Palo Alto Research Centre Smalltalk Nest ). That ( `Controller-part` ) design will introduce more re-work, than that of domain-specific `Model-part` ( doing actual processing of the UI-inputs ).

**`A4:`** Simply provide your own domain-specific `DataSET`, computed from Quant-model of the options-pricing, instead of the synthetic Gaussian.

[Options Pricing Models ZOO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWImO.png)

---

**`nota-bene:`** you might be interested in a thorough argumentation why market is by no means a random-walk, elaborated and presented by Stuart Gordon REID.
[- Random walk hypothesis and it's importance to quantitative finance](http://www.turingfinance.com/hacking-the-random-walk-hypothesis/)
[- Random walks down Wall Street ( also for derivatives )](http://www.turingfinance.com/random-walks-down-wall-street-stochastic-processes-in-python/)
One simply shall not believe all tweets around.

Enjoy the Quant-worlds, Drew.